# Boto3 S3 resource get stuck on "Object.get" method

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I try to get a pickle file from an S3 resource using the "Object.get()" method of the boto3 library **from several processes simultaneously**. This causes my program to get stuck **on one of the processes** (No exception raised and the program does not continue to the next line).

I tried to add a "Config" variable to the S3 connection. That didn't help.

```py
import pickle
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

s3_item = _get_s3_name(descriptor_key)  # Returns a path string of the desiered file
config = Config(connect_timeout=5, retries={'max_attempts': 0})
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', config=config)
bucket_uri = os.environ.get(*ct.S3_MICRO_SERVICE_BUCKET_URI)  # Returns a string of the bucket URI
estimator_factory_logger.debug(f"Calling s3 with item {s3_item} from URI {bucket_uri}")
model_file_from_s3 = s3.Bucket(bucket_uri).Object(s3_item)
estimator_factory_logger.debug("Loading bytes...")
model_content = model_file_from_s3.get()['Body'].read()  # <- Program gets stuck here
estimator_factory_logger.debug("Loading from pickle...")
est = pickle.loads(model_content)
```

No error message raised. It seems that the "get" method is stuck in a deadlock.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that we created a subprocess after our main process opened several threads in it. Apparently, This is a big No-No in Linux.
We fixed it by using "spawn" instead of "fork"

Answer (score 0):

Is there a possibility that one of the files in the bucket is just huge and program takes a long time to read?

If that's the case, as a debugging step I'd look into `model_file_from_s3.get()['Body']` object, which is `botocore.response.StreamingBody` object, and use `set_socket_timeout()`on it to try and force timeout.

https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html